# Regex match two letter only with one evenly occuring

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The following expression will match strings with even occurences of 'c':

```
^[^c]*(c[^c]*c[^c]*)*$
```

ccar(Yes), ccarc (No), cccarc (Yes)...

I would like to edit it to only match the inputs with letters 'c' and 'd' only:

ccddd(Yes), dddddccc (No), cccddcdddd (Yes)...

The number of 'd' can be either even or odd.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it should only allow `d` as the alternative to `c`, replace `[^c]` with `d`.

```
^d*(cd*cd*)*$
```

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestion on generating the FSA. Any good online site?

Comment: No idea. FSA is more of a theoretical or academic CS thing, working computer programmers rarely need to deal with them.